# Bad AC response from bridge circuit

Tags: bode-plot, frequency-response, bridge, strain-gage

Followup to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/694948/loss-of-2nd-order-behavior-on-2nd-order-low-pass-filter).

Hi. I have the following bridge circuit to simulate a strain gauge.

[image]

I am conducting an AC sweep of it as another part of my circuit (currently disconnected) that uses the output of the bridge circuit as a source, requires a signal analysis.

This is my response from the outputs. The magnitude is extremely low and I am unsure why that is the case. There is a variable resistor that varies in a sine wave at 100Hz but that is the only element that is frequency based and it only influences resistance, not reactance.

[image]

A suspicion I have is that the AC sweep might not successfully emulate the strain gauge as in a strain gauge, it is the resistance that changes at different frequencies and not the power source. However, I don't see how this results in the low output I am seeing.

Please let me know if more info is required.

Comment: Look in the documentation for the simulator to see what it says about how the voltage controlled resistors behave in an AC analysis. Clearly it works for transient analysis but, I think your suspicion might be right.