# LTSpice UniversalOpamp2 parameters

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, simulation

I am trying to use the UniversalOpamp2 in LTSpice, but I can't seem to find a description of what is parameter sets of the op amp. I of course know that Avol is open loop gain and GBW is gain bandwidth product but Slew is described as 10Meg? Is there a write up anywhere for the parameters of this op amp?

Br

Edba

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/529510/how-do-you-use-op-amps-in-a-design-in-ltspice shows many details and screenshots

Answer (score 5):

`Slew` is the slew rate and it's in V/s, so `10Meg` means 10 MV/s, or 10 V/μs. The value for `Rail` signifies how many V will the opamp have between its saturation levels and the supply rails (e.g. `Rail=2` means it will saurate at `Vcc-2`, `Rail=0` means rail-to-rail). `Ilimit` is the output current limit, and `Vos` is the offset voltage. `UniversalOpamp3*` have additional `Rin` and `Phimargin`, [retty self-explanatory.

The rest of the parameters belong to the `[SpecialFunctions]/ota`, which is partly described in the help under *LTspice > Circuit Elements > A. ...*, last part, or in the [undocumented ltwiki](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Undocumented_LTspice#OTA), and they represent settings for voltage and current levels (only valid in a `.NOISE` analysis).