# LTSPICE Dynamic Power / Voltage Slew Rate Controlled Source

Tags: ltspice, simulation

I was just curious if anyone has a dynamic Power or Voltage Slew Rate controlled source, that they could share of point me to.

I need the source to act as the stand in to an external power supply that has a maximum voltage slew rate of around 1V/ms and 10,000W.

I would like to keep it dynamic in a similar manner to the one shown in the FesZ Video shown below.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnKnuJd3-ec
[image]

This is to help me debug some issues that we have been seeing on our test bench when we use different power supplies.

The end behavior that I am looking for is for the source to never be capable of changing more than 1V/ms throughout anytime during the simulation.

Thank you all in advance!

-CB

Comment: Are you talking about an independent voltage source or a dependent source? If it is independent, just use a piecewise-linear source and you can make the slew rate be whatever you want it to be.

Comment: No it will be a dependent source, similar to the one shown in the picture.

Comment: What if you used `UniversalOpamp` (Level 2) as a buffer and set the `Slew` parameter?  Units are in `V/s`.  More info in this answer:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/529510/how-do-you-use-op-amps-in-a-design-in-ltspice/529541

Comment: "Slew rate" for a DC power supply? Also, `Ron` defaults to `1m` if set to zero, and `1n` `tr/tf` seems exaggerated for a `2m` period. Not lastly, the ideal diode (as defined with `Ron, Roff`, etc) has an `Ilimit` parameter, which can be used as a current limit. The `level=2` VCSW also has it.

Comment: _"...and 10,000W."_ - what does this mean?

Comment: 10,000W =  10,000 (Watts) = 10kW just communicating the power output of the power supply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the question's comments, you can leverage the `UniversalOpamp2` component (found in the component library under `[Opamps]`, towards the end) and its `Slew` parameter.

[image]

It also has an `Ilimit` parameter, but while limiting it seems to take some time to reach a steady-state and work properly (at least for me).  Regardless, if you require separate sourcing and sinking current limits you need to use something else.  Therefore, as also mentioned in the comments, you can use the `Ilimit` function that's built into the piecewise-linear diode model type you're using.  This makes the current sources unnecessary since you can simply put the two current limited diodes counter-parallel to each other.  Adding `Epsilon` smooths out the piecewise-linear transitions so it's easier for SPICE to crunch the numbers.

When <kbd>right-click</kbd> editing the `UniversalOpamp2` symbol you can change its parameters.  This is where `Slew` is and it's specified in `V/s`...so 1k for your application.  I used a `.param` to set this value easier outside the symbol, and also did the same for `Avol` and `GBW`.  I set those last two to a `.param` with a really high number (1 gig) to swamp out the non-ideal effects associated with those parameters.  Lastly, we need to set the `Ilimit` here to something higher than what your diodes are set to.  I used 1 amp.

[image]

The entire circuit and example waveform outputs are shown below.  Notice how the `fb` node is a slew-rate limited version of the input, and how the current through `R1` is limited to what our diodes are set to via their respective `Ilimit`.  At the end, there's a plot confirming that our 1000kV/s slew rate specification results in a ~1V per ~1ms slope.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Text of LTspice `.asc` file for above simulation:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1188 680
WIRE 352 -16 192 -16
WIRE 544 16 464 16
WIRE 688 16 608 16
WIRE 192 64 192 -16
WIRE 240 64 192 64
WIRE 352 80 352 -16
WIRE 352 80 304 80
WIRE 400 80 352 80
WIRE 464 80 464 16
WIRE 464 80 400 80
WIRE 688 80 688 16
WIRE 752 80 688 80
WIRE 864 80 752 80
WIRE 240 96 48 96
WIRE 752 112 752 80
WIRE 48 128 48 96
WIRE 864 128 864 80
WIRE 464 144 464 80
WIRE 544 144 464 144
WIRE 688 144 688 80
WIRE 688 144 608 144
WIRE -192 208 -192 176
WIRE -80 208 -80 176
WIRE 752 224 752 192
WIRE 864 224 864 192
WIRE 48 240 48 208
WIRE -192 320 -192 288
WIRE -80 320 -80 288
FLAG 48 240 0
FLAG -192 320 0
FLAG -80 320 0
FLAG -192 176 Vcc
FLAG 272 48 Vcc
FLAG -80 176 Vee
FLAG 272 112 Vee
FLAG 752 224 0
FLAG 864 224 0
FLAG 864 80 out
FLAG 48 96 in
FLAG 400 80 fb
SYMBOL voltage 48 112 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value PULSE(-5 5 0 1u 1u 50m 100m)
SYMBOL Opamps\\UniversalOpamp2 272 80 R0
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMATTR Value2 Avol={Avol} GBW={Avol} Slew={slew}
SYMATTR SpiceLine Ilimit=1 Rail=0 Vos=0
SYMBOL voltage -192 192 R0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL voltage -80 192 R0
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value -10
SYMBOL diode 544 32 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value source_lim
SYMBOL res 736 96 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 150
SYMBOL diode 608 160 M270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMATTR Value sink_lim
SYMBOL cap 848 128 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 10p
TEXT 280 392 Left 2 !.tran 250m
TEXT 16 296 Left 2 !.model source_lim D(Ron=1m Roff=1g Vfwd=0 Epsilon=10m Ilimit={Isource})\n.model sink_lim D(Ron=1m Roff=1g Vfwd=0 Epsilon=10m Ilimit={Isink})
TEXT -224 -32 Left 2 !.param Avol=1g\n.param slew=1k\n.param Isource=3m\n.param Isink=10m
```

---

An alternative approach, which runs quicker and doesn't require those Vcc/Vee power rails, would be to create your own idealized opamp model but add in the slew rate limiting portion.  I used [this hyperbolic tangent slew rate limit article as a reference](http://www.ecircuitcenter.com/OpModels/Tanh_Stage/Tanh_Stage.htm) to create the simulation below.  The same dual diode scheme as above is also used here for the current limiting.  As shown in the resulting waveform images, the same results are achieved.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Text of LTspice `.asc` file for above simulation:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1604 680
WIRE 1216 64 1136 64
WIRE 1360 64 1280 64
WIRE 16 128 -96 128
WIRE 816 128 352 128
WIRE 1040 128 816 128
WIRE 1136 128 1136 64
WIRE 1136 128 1040 128
WIRE 1360 128 1360 64
WIRE 1424 128 1360 128
WIRE 1536 128 1424 128
WIRE -96 160 -96 128
WIRE 352 160 352 128
WIRE 816 160 816 128
WIRE 1424 160 1424 128
WIRE 1040 176 1040 128
WIRE 1536 176 1536 128
WIRE 1136 192 1136 128
WIRE 1216 192 1136 192
WIRE 1360 192 1360 128
WIRE 1360 192 1280 192
WIRE -96 272 -96 240
WIRE 352 272 352 240
WIRE 816 272 816 240
WIRE 1040 272 1040 240
WIRE 1424 272 1424 240
WIRE 1536 272 1536 240
FLAG -96 272 0
FLAG 352 272 0
FLAG 816 272 0
FLAG 16 128 in
FLAG 1040 272 0
FLAG 352 128 fb
FLAG 1424 272 0
FLAG 1536 272 0
FLAG 1536 128 out
SYMBOL voltage -96 144 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value PULSE(-5 5 0 1u 1u 50m 100m)
SYMBOL bi 352 240 M180
WINDOW 0 24 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName B1
SYMATTR Value I=tanh((2*pi*Avol/slew)*V(in,fb))
SYMBOL cap 1024 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value {1/slew}
SYMBOL res 800 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value {slew/(2*pi)}
SYMBOL diode 1216 80 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value source_lim
SYMBOL res 1408 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 150
SYMBOL diode 1280 208 M270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMATTR Value sink_lim
SYMBOL cap 1520 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 10p
TEXT 648 464 Left 2 !.tran 250m
TEXT 216 328 Left 2 !.param Avol=1g\n.param slew=1k\n.param Isource=3m\n.param Isink=10m
TEXT 552 352 Left 2 !.model source_lim D(Ron=1m Roff=1g Vfwd=0 Epsilon=10m Ilimit={Isource})\n.model sink_lim D(Ron=1m Roff=1g Vfwd=0 Epsilon=10m Ilimit={Isink})
```

Comment: You can simplify the two diodes to only one with `ilimit` and `revilimit` (and appropriate `vfwd` and `vrev`). Or use a VCSW with `level=2`.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  Thanks for adding info about the `rev` stuff.  I didn't want to confuse the questioner since there's a bit of visual intuition when you see the two diodes pointed in opposite directions, and that's similar to what was started with.  Similar with the switch, it was absent from the original question and so I didn't want to deal with explaining it.  Can you post a link to an old answer of yours which gives a summary on how to use it and its `ilimit` in case someone reading the comments in the future would like to use that approach instead?

Comment: I don't think I have an answer like that, so just go ahead and add that however you wish. BTW, you could use the symbol for the `TVSdiode` with `revilimit`. But, if I'm not too wrong, I think the diode doesn't have a `tanh()` limiting, and the only "curvy" effect is that of the simple quadratic region given by the `epsilon` and `revepsilon` (I think it's slightly higher order, simple differentiation doesn't show discontinuities). For `tanh()` use either the `level=2` VCSW or the OTA with `iout` or `isrc/isink`.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  Ah, good point about the `TVSdiode`.  That definitely makes the visuals better.  I think the comments are sufficient to document this stuff (i.e. I'm too lazy to add anything).

Comment: Thank you guys for your help on this. I especially appreciate the visual aids! Your gut instinct was right @SteKulov. Thanks for the additional clarifications @a concerned citizen